# Single or multiprofile implementation of Google analytics for a webview app and website?

Tags: google-analytics, web-applications, universal-analytics

I have Googled around quite a bit, but didn't find any good resources to figure out the best way to implement Google analytics to track web application which has webview based mobile apps in addition to website.

All app users must be logged in and I report user-id's to google analytics.

I have currently three different properties for users to interact with the service we provide:
 1. Website
 2. Webview app for Android
 3. Webview app for IOS

I have implemented Google analytics with user id and some additional custom dimensions reporting for all properties of my service.

Mobile webview based apps load in some of the excisting website content, so mobile apps usage gets partially tracked by the website google analytics profile currently.

Should I have for every application property different google analytics profile or use single one for all of them?

I see that with single one I could get better cross-device usage statistics, but it would make tracking every property on it's own harder.

Answer (score 1):

Your Solution is something like this - 1 GA Profile > Create 3 Property > Implement user id only for web property & please cross check your SDK code correctly implemented into the Android & IOS app. (Please Refer Attached Screen-shots[image])

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I have today.

I thought if it would make sense to accomodate all under one GA property.

Comment: It's not possible because of every property own a unique table id in the Analytics Developer Console.